# What is the divine wisdom in abrogating a verse an hour after revelation (Quran 58:12-13)

Tags: quran, tafseer, doubts

> O you who have believed, when you [wish to] privately consult the Messenger, present before your consultation a charity. That is better for you and purer. But if you find not [the means] - then indeed, Allāh is Forgiving and Merciful.
> [Quran 58:12]

The above verse is said to be abrogated by the next verse after an hour of revelation -

> Have you feared to present before your consultation charities? Then when you do not and Allāh has forgiven you, then [at least] establish prayer and give zakāh and obey Allāh and His Messenger. And Allāh is Aware of what you do.
> [Quran 58:13]

From the abridged translation of Tafsir Ibn Kathir -

> Sa`id bin Abi `Arubah reported from Qatadah and Muqatil bin Hayyan,
>
> "People kept questioning Allah's Messenger until they made things
> difficult for him. Allah provided a way to stop their behavior by this
> Ayah. One of them would need to speak to Allah's Prophet about a real
> matter, but could not do so until he gave in charity. This became hard
> on people and Allah sent down relief from this requirement afterwards,
>
> فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ غَفُورٌ رَّحِيمٌ
>
> But if you find not, then verily, Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most
> Merciful)."

> Abdur-Razzaq recorded that Mujahid said that Ali said,
>
> "No one except me implemented this Ayah, until it was abrogated,"
>
> and he was reported to have said that it remained in effect for merely
> an hour

What is the divine wisdom here? Didn't Allah know that people would not accept the ruling easily?

Also, I have heard many dayis say that the wisdom of abrogation is - the people would find it difficult to give up their pre Islamic practices suddenly so it provides a way to gradually ease them into the ultimate ruling (e. g. Alcohol, fasting). But that reasoning doesn't apply here.

Finally, doesn't this contradict the following ayah, because this doesn't bring anything better or similar -

> We do not abrogate a verse or cause it to be forgotten except that We
> bring forth [one] better than it or similar to it. Do you not know
> that Allāh is over all things competent? [Quran 2:106]